# How does 'yield' work in tornado when making an asynchronous call?

Tags: python, asynchronous, generator, tornado, yield

Recently, I was learning ***Introduction to Tornado***, and I came across the following code:

```
class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    @tornado.gen.engine
    def get(self):
        query = self.get_argument('q')
        client = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
        response = yield tornado.gen.Task(client.fetch,
                "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?" + \
                urllib.urlencode({"q": query, "result_type": "recent", "rpp": 100}))
        body = json.loads(response.body)

        [...omitted the following code...]
```

I used to learn that `yield` is the key word turning a common function into a generator,  and when it used in the form `other = yield foo` means, **"yield foo and, when a value is sent to me, set other to that value."** So I tried the following code in ipython:

```
In [1]: result = 'init'     #set a global variable

In [2]: def test_yield():
   ...:     global result
   ...:     print 'start test...'
   ...:     result = yield 'foo'
   ...:     print 'end test...'
   ...:     

In [3]: t = test_yield()

In [4]: t.next()
start test...
Out[4]: 'foo'  #'foo' has been yield to the caller, and blocked
```

Now I printed the global varialbe `result`, and it still referred to string 'init':

```
In [5]: print result
init
```

Then I called the `send()` method, and sent a new string to `yield`:

```
In [6]: t.send('new message')
end test...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/chiyu/<ipython-input-6-b86312ad7d0e> in <module>()
----> 1 t.send('new message')

StopIteration:
```

As expected, a `StopIteration` was raised and output the string 'end test...', but now the global variable `result` has been changed:

```
In [7]: print result
new message
```

Apperantly, the `yield` statement accepted the string when we called the `send()` method, and assigned the new string to the variable result.

**MY QUESTION IS:**

Back to the code showed on the top, according to this logic,

```
response = yield tornado.gen.Task(client.fetch,
                    "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?" + \
                    urllib.urlencode({"q": query, "result_type": "recent", "rpp": 100}))
```

when method `client.fetch` returned, a `Task` instance would be created and `yield` to the caller, but the variable `response` on the left will recieve nothing because no `send()` method has been excuted. I got quite confused about this, and googled in vain.

**I would be really appreciated for your explanations!**

Comment: `client.fetch` is not being called; it is only being *referenced*. The `Task()` object will take care of actually calling it.

Comment: And what makes you think that Tornado won't use `send()` on your generator?

Comment: What is `client` here, is it an instance of  `tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are *already* understanding how Tornado uses generators to handle async calls.

I'm assuming here that `client` is an instance of [`tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()`](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/httpclient.html#tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient); it's `fetch()` method takes a callback function.

The [`tornado.gen.Task`](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/gen.html#tornado.gen.Task) object only takes a *reference to the `client.fetch` method*; you are not calling it at that point. You are constructing a `Task()` instance with that method reference and an argument, then yielding that.

Tornado will then run that `Task`; the `Task` will in turn call `client.fetch()` with the argument provided, *plus a callback function*. The `client.fetch()` then runs asynchronously, and calls the callback. Whatever is then passed to the callback is then recorded as the `Task` result.

That result is then sent to your `IndexHandler.get()` generator with `send()`, returned from the `yield Task()` expression and assigned to `response`.

In other words, Tornado **does** use `.send()` here and something *is* assigned to `response`.

Answer (score 5):

It sort of means "I give up control to you; come back when you have the result of this Future", and is thus kind of like an asynchronous dereferencing operator. Tornado responds by `send`ing back the result when it's ready.

See http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/gen.html for a more in-depth explanation.